# How can I feed API Subgraph data into Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to pull / import API data from theGraph into Google Sheets ( GS ) Then feed the imported data to columns / rows in a GS spreadsheet.

The solution by @Theza to the question ( Google Sheets: json into columns ) does this nicely and I have tried to use this as a starting point.

Editing the URL & query results in the data I want being pulled correctly and is displayed in the log

I cannot work out how I then get the logged info to feed to my spreadsheet ?!

Some help would be much appreciated :)

Below is the Apps Script I am working from:

```
function graphData(query,url){
  var options = {"headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"
                            },
                 "payload": JSON.stringify({query}),
                 "method": "POST"
                };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
  return response;
};

function Pool () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  sheet.appendRow(["pool-id", "token0Name", "token1Name", "token0Price", "token1Price"]);
  // Original url
  //var url = 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/openpredict/chainlink-prices-subgraph' ;
  
  // MY API
  var url = 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/stellaswap/pulsar' ;

  // Original query
  //var query = 'query{prices(first:2 where:{assetPair_in:["USDC/ETH","DAI/ETH "]} orderBy:timestamp orderDirection:desc) {assetPair{id} timestamp price}}';
  
  // MY QUERY
  var query = 'query { pool(id: "0x1b11d991f32fb59ec4ee744de68ad65d9e85b2d2") { id token0 { name } token1 { name } token0Price token1Price } }';


  var a=graphData(query,url);
  var code= a.getContent();
  var json = a.getContentText(); // get the response content as text

  var mae = JSON.parse(json); //parse text into json
  
   // How do I edit the following to feed the log (response) data to columns / rows in the GS spreadsheet

  var rows = [],dat,lastR=sheet.getLastRow()+1;
  mae.data.prices.forEach(x => {rows[rows.length]=[x.assetPair.id,x.timestamp,x.price];});
  sheet.getRange('A'+lastR+':C'+(lastR+rows.length-1)).setValues(rows);
  }
```